# Group of order $1575$ having a normal Sylow $3$ subgroup is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Question is to prove that :

If a group $G$ with $|G|=1575=3^2\cdot5^2\cdot 7$ has a normal Sylow $3$ subgroup then :

- Sylow $5$ subgroup is normal
- Sylow $7$ subgroup is normal

In this situation, Prove that $G$ is abelian.

All i can do is  :

If Sylow $3$ subgroup, Sylow $5$ subgroup, Sylow $7$ subgroup is normal then $G$ is abelian.

Notation : $P_3$ for Sylow $3$ subgroup ;$P_5$ for Sylow $5$ subgroup; $P_7$ for Sylow $7$ subgroup

We know that  :

> For $H\leq G$  the quotient group $N_G(H)/C_G(H)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\text{Aut(H)}$.

- As $P_3\unlhd G$ we have $N_G(P_3)=G$
- As $P_5\unlhd G$ we have $N_G(P_5)=G$
- As $P_7\unlhd G$ we have $N_G(P_7)=G$

Thus, we will have

> The quotient group $G/C_G(P_i)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\text{Aut($P_i$)}$ for $i=3,5,7$.

---

In case of $P_3$ we have $G/C_G(P_3)\cong M \leq \text{Aut($P_3$)}$

Now, $|P_3|=3^2$ so, $|\text{Aut($P_3$)}|=3(3-1)=6$

As $C_G(P_3)\leq G$ we see that $|C_G(P_3)|$ divides $|G|$ with the condition $|G/C_G(P_3)|$ divides $6$.

As $P_3$ is abelian we have $H\leq C_G(P_3)$ so, $G/C_G(P_3) \leq G/P_3$

i.e., $G/C_G(P_3)\leq G/P_3$ i.e., $|G/C_G(P_3)|$ divides $|G/P_3|=5^2\cdot7$

we already have a condition that $|G/C_G(P_3)|$ divides $6$.

But, $6$ and $5^2.7$ do not have a common factor other than $1$ so, $|G/C_G(P_3)|=1$

i.e., $C_G(P_3)=G$ i.e., $P_3\leq Z(G)$.

---

In case of $P_5$ we have $G/C_G(P_5)\cong M \leq \text{Aut($P_5$)}$

Now, $|P_5|=5^2$ so, $|\text{Aut($P_5$)}|=5(5-1)=20$

As $C_G(P_5)\leq G$ we see that $|C_G(P_5)|$ divides $|G|$ with the condition $|G/C_G(P_5)|$ divides $20$.

As $P_5$ is abelian we have $H\leq C_G(P_5)$ so, $G/C_G(P_5) \leq G/P_5$

i.e., $G/C_G(P_5)\leq G/H$ i.e., $|G/C_G(P_5)|$ divides $|G/P_5|=3^2\cdot7$

we already have a condition that $|G/C_G(P_5)|$ divides $20$.

But, $20$ and $3^2.7$ do not have a common factor other than $1$ so, $|G/C_G(P_5)|=1$

i.e., $C_G(P_5)=G$ i.e., $P_5\leq Z(G)$.

---

In case of $P_7$ we have $G/C_G(P_7)\cong M \leq \text{Aut($P_7$)}$

Now, $|P_7|=7$ so, $|\text{Aut($P_3$)}|=(7-1)=6$

As $C_G(P_7)\leq G$ we see that $|C_G(P_7)|$ divides $|G|$ with the condition $|G/C_G(P_7)|$ divides $6$.

As $P_7$ is abelian we have $H\leq C_G(P_7)$ so, $G/C_G(P_7) \leq G/P_7$

i.e., $G/C_G(P_7)\leq G/P_7$ i.e., $|G/C_G(P_7)|$ divides $|G/P_7|=3^2\cdot7$

we already have a condition that $|G/C_G(P_7)|$ divides $6$.

Now there is a hitch....

I can not use same arguments as i have used for $P_3$ and $P_5$ as $3$ does divide $6$ and $3^2.7$.

So, I can not immediately conclude $|G/C_G(P_7)|=1$ i.e., $G=C_G(P_7)$ i.e., $P_7\leq Z(G)$.

---

Assuming I have Proved  $P_i\leq Z(G)$ for $i=3,5,7$

It would not take much time to conclude $G=Z(G)$

As $P_i\cap P_j =\{e\}$ for $i\neq j$ and $i,j\in \{3,5,7\}$ we see that $G=\langle P_3,P_5,P_7\rangle$

But then $P_i\leq Z(G)$ for $i=3,5,7$ i.e., $G =\langle P_3,P_5,P_7\rangle \leq Z(G)$

i.e., $G=Z(G)$ which means $G$ is abelian.

---

So, I am done on more than $40$ percent of the problem leaving possibility of $|G/C_G(P_7)|=3$ and I do not really understand how to make use of $P_3$ being Normal to conclude $P_5$ and $P_7$ are Normal.

I am not sure of the procedure but I have something to say  on $P_5$ being normal :

As $P_3$ is normal I can consider $G/P_3$ with $|G/P_3|=5^2.7$

So, If i see this group as something named $M$ This subgroup have

- a Sylow $5$ subgroup and
- a Sylow $7$ subgroup.

But the condition $n_5=1+5k$ dividing $7$ gives only possibility that $n_5=1$

Which means that Sylow $5$ subgroup of $M$ (I wish i could make this as $P_5$) is normal.

With similar reason $n_7=1+7k$ dividing $5^2$ gives only possibility that $n_7=1$

Which means that Sylow $7$ subgroup of $M$ (I wish I could make this as $P_7$) is normal.

So I guess I am done up to $60$ percent.

I am not so sure how to make use of (believing that I can make use of) Sylow $5$ subgroup, Sylow $7$ subgroup of $M$ being normal to conclude $P_5$ and $P_7$ are normal.

I would be thankful if some one can help me to clear two gaps in this :

- How to get rid of $|G/C_G(P_7)|=3$.
- How to make use of Sylow $5$ subgroup, Sylow $7$ subgroup of $M$ being normal to conclude $P_5$ and $P_7$ are normal.

Please help me to clear these gaps.

Thank you.

P.S : Please give "just hints". Do not write whole answer at once. This is a "request". Thank you :)

Comment: I love your percentages.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : I would take it as a compliment :)

Comment: I think Sylow theorem is important in this problem.

Comment: @WeiZhou : Yes... It is important... So?

Comment: Are you assuming that both Sylow 3- and 5-subgroups are cyclic? When you calculate the order of their automorphism groups I think you have to consider the cases of being elementary abelian too!

Comment: @NickyHekster :  I am not assuming they are cyclic.. they are just abelian

Comment: In that case you have to consider $P_3 \cong C_3 \times C_3$ too, whence Aut$(P_3) \cong SL(2,3)$. Same for the prime 5.

Comment: By Sylow theorem, $P_5$, $P_7$ are normal in $G$. Note that If $A, B$ are normal in $G$ and $(|A|, |B|)=1$, then $A\le C_G(A)$ and $B\le C_G(A)$. Then...

Comment: @WeiZhou : Could you please explain how does one conclude $P_5$ and $P_7$ are normal with sylow theorem?

Comment: @NickyHekster : Yes but that does not change the order of automorphism group right :O

Comment: 1 $P_3$ is in center of G, as your proof. 2 $P_5,P_7$ normal by Sylow theorem as Serkan. 3 G is abelian by my last comment.

Comment: @WeiZhou :  I am sorry, I didn't get you... Is that some theorem "Note that If A,B are normal in G and $(|A|,|B|)=1$, then $A≤C_G(A)$ and $B≤C_G(A)$." Even if that hold how can i conlcude the required result from that?

Comment: @NickyHekster : Ok Ok.. please suggest me some approach which will lead to the solution....

Comment: Yes it does change the order of the automorphism group: $|GL(2,p)|=(p^2-1)(p^2-p)$, but never mind, I just wanted to show you that your approach does not lead to the solution.

Comment: Since all Sylow subgroups are normal, $G=P_3P_5P_7$. Note that all sylow subgroups are abelian. And elements in different Sylow subgroups are commute, we know G is abelian.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint: Pull back Sylow subgroups of $G/P_3$, which are normal, and use the fact that if a Sylow subgroup is normal then it is characteristic.

Comment: I do not get your point.. could you please extend this a bit...

Comment: The preimage of Sylow 5(resp. 7)-subgroup of $G/P_3$ is normal in $G$ and it has a normal, hence characteristic Sylow 5(resp. 7)-subgroup. Then it must be (why?) a Sylow 5(resp. 7)-subgroup of $G$.

Comment: I am sorry for late reply... There was problem with my computer... we consider $\eta : G\rightarrow G/P_3$ then you are asking me to cvonsider $\eta^{-1}(M_1)$ where $M_1$ is that normal sbgroup of $G/P_3$ but why would $\eta^{-1}(M_1)$ is normal if $\eta$ is just a homomorphism(surjective)

Comment: Oh yes.... I got it... but why do we need being characteristic... :O I am sorry I am messing it up!

Comment: OH my Bad.. I got it now!!! Perfect!! Thank you!! could you please help me to look at the case of $|C_G(P_7)|=3$

Comment: Ok.. So I do not have to prove that $C_G(P_7)=G$ seperately?

Comment: Fine Fine.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If $|G/C(P_7)|=3$ then $|C(P_7)|=3*5^2*7$, now $3^2$ divides $|Z(G)|$ and $5^2$ divides $|Z(G)|$. So $|Z(G)|$ is greater or equal to $3^2*5^2$, so $|Z(G)|=3^2*5^2$ or $3^2*5^2*7$  but $Z(G)$ is subgroup of $C(P_7)$ so $|Z(G)|$ divides $|C(P_7)|$, but in either case $|Z(G)|$ can not divide $|C(P_7)|$, so $|C(P_7)|\ne 3$, which implies $|C(P_7)|=1$.Hence $|G/C(P_7)|=1$ and $P_7$ is contained in $Z(G)$ ,hence $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use Mathjax.