# Prove that if $G$ is a group of order $315$ with a normal sylow-3 subgroup is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

> Prove that if $G$ is a group of order $315$ with a normal sylow-$3$ subgroup is abelian.

My approach:

Let $|G| = 3^2.5.7$.

If we can show that $Z(G)$ contains the sylow $3$ subgroup then $|G/Z(G)|=5,7$ or $35$ or $1$.In all the cases we can conclude that the group $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic so $G$ is abelian.

** Showing that $Z(G)$ contains the sylow-$3$ subgroup **

Let $H$ denote the normal sylow-$3$ subgroup of $G$.

Let us consider a group action of conjugation from $G$ to $H$ given by

$$G \mapsto{\rm Aut}(H)$$

$$ \varphi:g \mapsto \sigma_g$$

$$\sigma_g(h) \mapsto g.h.g^{-1}$$

Then we know that this is a well defined homomorphism such that $\ker(\varphi) = \{g \in G:ghg^{-1} = h ;\forall h \in H\}$. Also $Z(G) \le \ker(\varphi)$

We know that the centre of a $p$ group is non-empty so $\ker(\varphi)$  $\ne \{e\}$.

Since $|H| = 9$ then $H \cong \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ or $H \cong \mathbb{Z}_9$

Case 1:$H \cong \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$

Then ${\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3) \cong (\mathbb{Z}_3)^* \times (\mathbb{Z}_3)^* \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ . Then $|{\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3)| = 4 $

Then $|G/\ker(\varphi)| \mid 4$ which is only possible if $\ker(\varphi) = G$ so $H$ commutes with all the elements of $G$ hence $H$ is contained in $Z(G)$.

Case 2:${\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_9) \cong (\mathbb{Z}_9)^*$ then $|(\mathbb{Z}_9)^*| = 6$.Then $|G/\ker(\varphi)| \mid 6$

$|G/\ker(\varphi)| = 1$ or $2$ or $3$ or $6$.

case (A):Then $|G/\ker(\varphi)| = 1$ then $G = ker(\varphi)$ then we are done so $H$ commutes with every-elements of $G$ hence $H$ is contained in $Z(G)$

Case(B):$|G/\ker(\varphi)| = 2$ then $2 \mid 315$ not possible.

Case(C): If $|G/\ker(\varphi)| = 3$ then $\ker(\varphi)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and is of order 105.Now $\ker(\varphi)$ is abelian also as it contains a normal  sylow -$3$ subgroup. Now $G/\ker(\varphi)$ is a cylic group.

Let $x,y \in H$ then $x.y = y.x$ [As $H$ is abelian]

Let $h_1 \in H$ , $y \in G/H$ then $h_1.a.h = a.h_2.h$.**This is where I am stuck.Is it possible to show a contradiction from here**

Case(D):It is easy to see that this is a contradiction as $\ker(\varphi) \ne \{e\}$

It would be really helpful if someone goes through my approach and points out my mistake or a conclusion.

Comment: Case (1) is not correct: The automorphism group of $C_3\times C_3$ is the general linear group $GL(2,3)$ of order $48$.  I don't understand your case (2A).

Comment: I have written an answer to a similar question recently making us of semi-direct products. You can find my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4228988/907711). I think that the same logic applies to your question as well.

Comment: If $|G/ker(\varphi)| \mid 6 $ then $G/ker(\varphi) = 1,2,3$ or$ 6$ .CAse 2(A) says that if $|G/ker(\varphi) = 1$ then $G = ker(\varphi)$ so $H$ commutes with every-elements of $G$ hence $H$ is contained in $Z(G)$

Comment: How do I go around Case 2(C)?

Comment: You can eliminate many of your problems by noting that $H$ is abelian. The group action $G\to \mathrm{Aut}(H)$ is actually a map $G/C_G(H)\to \mathrm{Aut}(H)$. Since $H\leq C_G(H)$, the group on the left-hand side is a $3'$-group.